# Access a member of all structs in an array

Tags: c++

I have a struct Foo;

```
typedef struct {

    int bar;
    char baz;

} Foo;
```

Suppose I then declare an array of Foo as;

```
Foo* arr = new Foo[300];
```

And proceed to initialize every member with a loop. I would like very much to be able to get an array of all members bar;

```
int* barr_arr = ...
```

What is the most efficient way to do this? Is there some way to exploit the memory layout such that I need not loop over the entire Foo array?

Since we know the memory layout in advance could we exploit the fact that we know the address of every member if we're clever about alignment?

Comment: *I would like very much to be able to get an array of all members bar;* Why? What's the real problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: You cannot obtain a plain `int*` from your `Foo*` because there are strings in between the ints (so the normal pointer arithmetics would already lead to undefined behavior). What you can do in C++ is build iterators that represent the ints in this range which you can then use with all STL functionality. By the way, you should decide between C and C++ in your tagging.

Comment: @RSahu I have data where sometimes I need to look at all the bar, baz, etc. of one element, and other times I need to look at all the baz but don't care about the bar at all.

For example, say I have a grid of earth, air, and sky depths. Sometimes I need to know the depth of each in a given cell, sometimes I need to know the depth of the ground in every cell.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I removed the string from the example - my datatypes are mainly numeric, and tricks from C may well apply.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is still not C. You need to decide which language are you using since answers might differ as well. They are not the same!

Comment: It doesn't matter what you have in between. Pointer arithmetics will simply fail you.

Comment: If you're using `new` in your actual code, C++ is the right tag. What @sidyll is trying to emphasize is that, though you can write C++ that looks almost entirely like C code, there are significant differences in standardized behavior and compilers that are highly relevant, especially for a question like this.

Comment: That's not reason enough to create a `int*` that points to array that holds all the `bar` members of `Foo`. You can pass references to `Foo` and pull out the `bar` member. I don't think it's that big of a hassle.

Comment: @sidyll sorry, you're right, the 'new' keyword makes this only C++. Removed tag.

Comment: @RSahu: Depends. If he needs to pass an array of `bar`s to some other API, he has to construct it somehow.

Comment: @RSahu a concrete example might be that I want to send a contiguous array of bar's to a GPU for parallel processing

Comment: @Linuxios has it.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the most efficient way to do this? Is there some way to exploit the memory layout such that I need not loop over the entire Foo array?

I don't think there is away to do that without looping. You can simplify your code by using `std::transform` but `std::transform` does loop.

Also, I would recommend using `std::vector` instead of allocating an array using `new`.

```
std::vector<Foo> arr(300);

....


std::vector<int> bArr(arr.size());
std::transform(arr.begin(), arr.end(), bArr.begin(), [] -> (Foo const& f) { return f.bar; });
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are initializing the first array, you can grab a pointer to the field inside each element and store that in a separate array.

```
struct Foo
{
    int bar;
    float baz;
};

const int SIZE = 5;
Foo foos[SIZE];
int *bars[SIZE];
for(int c = 0; c < SIZE; c++) {
    foos[c].bar = c;
    foos[c].baz = c;
    bars[c] = &foos[c].bar; // Grab pointer to field
}

for(int c = 0; c < SIZE; c++) {
    std::cout << "Bar Value: " << *bars[c] << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `Foo`s typically exist in arrays, and corresponding arrays of `bar`s and `baz`s often need to be accessed, I would suggest redesigning your data structures to better suit your problem. Obviously, we're not reading the code that inspired this question, but given the information provided, I might suggest something like:

```
struct FooArray {
  int* bars;
  char* bazes;
  size_t n_elements;
};
```

This removes the need to allocate a new buffer for the `bar` array, which, depending on how many `Foo`s are being processed, might entail significant memory savings.

I would also note that, if you're not working at a low level and don't actually need an `int*` but can do with a `std::vector<int>`, then @R Sahu's answer is likely a more appropriate solution.

Comment: While this is a solution I considered, the issue I have is sometimes I want fast access to e.g. Foo[3] and all its members. 

I suppose I would be be better served by finding out which of these my code spends more time in, and optimize in that direction.

Comment: @user1151695: I don't think that indexing a few integer arrays is "slow"... you can always write a convenience function to do it for you. Allocation, on the other hand...

Comment: @user1151695: But yes. Profile first, optimize second :).

Answer (score 1):

The goal drives the design.

If your main use is to pass all `bar` members in a row, same for `baz` members, then create separate containers:

```
std::vector<int> bar;
std::vector<char> baz;
```

Then passing `bar` as an array is straightforward: just use `bar.data()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a constructor to your `Foo` that takes the size of array, you could have only one object of `Foo`. You can then make it that you can access either the whole vector data or individual elements with subscript:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct Foo
{
    std::vector<int> bars;
    std::vector<char> bazs;
    std::size_t size;

    Foo(size_t size, int bar = 0, char baz = 0) :
        bars(size, bar), bazs(size, baz), size{size}
    {
    }

    auto operator[](size_t n)
    {
        // if (n >= size) ...
        struct
        {
            int &bar;
            char &baz;
        } temp{ bars[n], bazs[n] };
        return temp;
    }
};


int main()
{
    Foo arr(30, 100, 'a'); // 30 items

    std::cout << arr[29].bar << std::endl;
    std::cout << arr[29].baz << std::endl;

    std::cout << arr.bars[29] << std::endl;
    std::cout << arr.bazs[29] << std::endl;

    std::unique_ptr<Foo> arr2 = std::make_unique<Foo>(25, 10, 'b'); // 25 items

    std::cout << arr2->operator[](15).bar << std::endl;
    std::cout << arr2->operator[](15).baz << std::endl;

    arr2->bars[15] = 11;
    std::cout << arr2->bars[15] << std::endl;
    arr2->bazs[15] = 'c';
    std::cout << arr2->bazs[15] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/TiVwOT

```
100
a
100
a
10
b
11
c
```

Comment: This is making a guess about what OP is really trying to do. It's a good guess, but the question would be better if the guessing was not needed